# same binary image - different in python & matlab

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing

OK.  I'm thoroughly confused.  I have a binary image.  The values are (allegedly) 0 and 1.  I read it in Matlab, to verify:

```
binaryImage = imread('binary.png');
```

I get the max and min values, and the values are 1 and 0, respectively.

```
maxValue = max(binaryImage(:));
minValue = max(binaryImage(:));
```

I take the same exact binary image, and read it in Python...

```
from scipy.misc import imread
```

to get the pixel values we flatten it

```
li = img.flatten()

# check each value
for s in li:
    print s
```

The values, according to Python, are 0 and **255**.

So... does this mean if I use C++ (ITK) I will get a different value?  If I use OpenCV I will get a different value?  (Technically the "on" values should only be 1 and 255, but you know what I mean.)

If the pixel is "on" (white), and I set the value to 1 (in a binary image), no matter what language I read it in, I expect to see **1** for that value.

How come it's different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matlab supports logical arrays and scipy converts the image to grayscale. Depending on what you want to do you can convert the grayscale image to logicals

```
bit_img = img > 127
```

or convert the logical array to int8 in matlab

```
img = int8(binary_image) * 255
```

Comment: I think everyone around me heard me go, "Ohhhh!" :)  (Lightbulb!)  Thank you.